# NtexJS/NodeJS app when build results in TypeError: navigator.getUserMedia is not a function

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, next.js, getusermedia

I have a NextJS app with ExpressJS. it basically requests audio from a user in the browser and sends it to someone.

Now locally when I run `node server.js` it all works. But when I run `next build` and the `NODE_ENV=production node server.js` I get the following error for trying to requets media:

> TypeError: navigator.getUserMedia is not a function

This is the code causing that issue:

```
navigator.getUserMedia({ audio: true },
        () => {
            console.log('Permission Granted');
            this.setState({ isBlocked: false });
        },
        () => {
            console.log('Permission Denied');
            this.setState({ isBlocked: true })
        },
    );
}
```

Does anyone know why?

Comment: Ok i think the issue is on a Not secure browser connection I do not have access.

Comment: Perhaps you're running this on the server side, in this case you could do a checking for `if (typeof window === 'undefined') // this is server side` or check [how to do progessive rendering](https://github.com/zeit/next.js/blob/canary/examples/progressive-render/pages/index.js)